# Should all the identifiers of static properties with accessors start with uppercase letters?

Tags: f#, properties

I can't see anywhere that this should be the case, but I get an "Invalid declaration syntax" error in the `get` everytime I declare a static property that does not start with an uppercase letter. E.g:

```
type Foo() = class
    static member bar 
        with get() = "bar" //Invalid declaration syntax in get
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a bug in Beta2/October CTP.  It only affects static properties that use the 'with get/set' syntax.  You can use just the shorter syntax

```
static member bar = "bar"
```

as a workaround, assuming you only need a getter.

Comment: In fact, that's all I need so I used this solution :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question 'yes'. Property names should be capitalized as per the .NET coding guidelines. Unless you have a specific reason to have it be a lower case identifier, please have it be PascalCased.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Interesting, because I am transferring code from C# to F# and with the C# I don't have that problem.